# Having styling issue

Tags: reactjs

Here's my css code:

```
.wrapper{
  background-image: url(../src/img/wallhaven-6qj55q.jpg);
}


.container{
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;

  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 25vh;
  
}
```

and here's my js code:

```
import './App.css';
import FormBox from './component/FormBox';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="container">
       <FormBox />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm trying to cover the whole background up but it's only doing partical. What is my issue here?[image]

Comment: The height of the .wrapper class div matters since the background is applied to it. As long it is the more of the picture you'll see.

Answer (score 1):

Try min-height 100vh for your wrapper

```
.wrapper{
  background-image: url(../src/img/wallhaven-6qj55q.jpg);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```